# How to show a HTML element on the same row the element is clicked javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, click

I have a scenario, in which Person 1 and a icon is displayed in first row. On click of Add Person button, Person 2 and a icon gets added in the second row and so on. When i click on the icon , I display a list of elements using a  ul element. The issue ul always displays in the first row position irrespective of the row i clicked.
ul should be displayed on that particular row, where the icon is clicked. Any help on this is appreciated. I have provided the code below.

```
 <div *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index ">
      <div>
         <input id="form3" class="form-control" type="text">
         <label for="form3" class="">{{person.name}}</label>
      </div>

      <a href='#'  data-target='dropdown2' (click)="shareIconClicked($event, i)"></a> //icon to click

       // on click of above link , below li gets displayed
       <ul id='dropdown2' *ngIf="i<1" [ngClass]="{'popupShare': showPopup == true}" class='dropdown-content sharebtn-content'>
            <li>List item 1</li>
            <li>List item 2 </li>        
       </ul>
  </div>

 <button (click)="addNewRow()">Add Person</button>


// component code
ngOnInit() {
    this.showPopup = false;
    this.persons = [
      { 'name': 'Person 1' }
    ];

  }
 addNewRow() {
    this.persons.push({ 'name': 'Person ' + (this.persons.length + 1) });
  }


shareIconClicked($event: Event, i) {
    this.showPopup = true;
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
  }


.popupShare {
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    left: 198.594px;
    top: 16px;
    height: 153px;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
}

.dropdown-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
.sharebtn-content {
    width: 180px !important;
    left: 47.15px !important;
}
```

Comment: You could make that ul position `absolute` and passing to it a margin-top derived from the mouse click

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: Look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtccwm @Jessy

Comment: if the ul has a the property `position: absolute` the only problem I see is a `z-index` one

Comment: Actually this works partially fine. Until rows 4 or 5 it displays fine, but as more number of rows gets added , the popup moves towards top. I used  this.offsetY = $event.clientY - 500;  Since the margin-top was more, I used -500 to display it .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggle()` method of HTML DOM `classList` property to add/remove a CSS class

Note that `#listItem` added to `ul`

```
<a href='#'  data-target='dropdown2' (click)="listItem.classList.toggle('hidden')"></a> 

// on click of above link , below li gets displayed
<ul id='dropdown2 hidden' #listItem>
   ...    
</ul>
```

And a CSS class should be defined:

```
.hidden{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your answer is irrelevant to my question. My question is about displaying the ul on the row where it has been clicked.

Comment: So you mean that the `ul` will not be in *ngFor but will be added after click?

Comment: Yes. ul be added only after click , if i try to print i value inside ul , it is always 0, whereas outside ul , i value increases based on the row number ( first row , i is 1...)

Comment: I mean, will there be 1 and only 1 `ul` in the whole page or every row will have its own `ul`? If there will be more than 1 `ul`, then my answer should work.

Comment: Ideally its a single ul. When i click on first row icon , a pop up will be displayed. When i click on second row, the first pop up will be hidden and the second will be displayed. The issue here is in not displaying the pop up or hiding it, it is in positioning the pop  up. The pop up always gets displayed in the first position

Comment: Adding your code gives error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Comment: It's ok now. The other answers that are proposing positioning the `ul` is what you need then :) And for the `undefined` error, you have to add `#listItem` to your `ul` in `ngFor` to define it.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information about css and positioning, -> If I understand correctly you want an icon which is something like an action menu to pop up in row. I suppose you have some position: absolute or fixed on that ul, please provide css of: popupShare, dropdown-content, sharebtn-content

**From what is shown I can only tell that make sure that the ul has position relative or none position is defined, than make sure that the ul will be in html semantics inside the row, also an example on jsfiddle would be nice.**

-- EDIT AFTER CSS STYLES ADDED --

A solution or good approach might be to put the whole ul - li dropdown menu to component in a variable, which you will append dynamically to clicked row. Then all you need is just position it horizontally according to icon position, but this is the way how most of such plugins works as well.

Comment: Added the styles

Comment: I see your answer, what I would do is, just create that ul menu in your component and then append it to the row using: const dropdown = 'your dynamic ul element'
const element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);  -> so you will dynamically add / destroy the ul element from clicked row.